# Output after removing programs using WMI - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using WMI to uninstall software remotely and it's working fine to remove the software. What I'm struggling with is using the results of that (Successful or not) to give a simple out put message rather than the normal output of the command.  I normally use $lastexitcode for this but no matter whether or not the command succeeds it runs to my successful uninstall message.  Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName "$computer" | where { $_.vendor -eq "APN, LLC" }
$app.Uninstall()
if ($lastexitcode -eq 0)
        {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Programm Successfully Removed"
        }    
    else
        {
        write-host -ForegroundColor red "There was a problem uninstalling the program"
        }
```

When I leave output of the operation on it returns:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

I figure I could do something with the ReturnValue but I'm not sure how.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: The solution thanks to Bruce's answer:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName "$computer" | where { $_.vendor -eq "APN, LLC" }
$appuninstall = $app.Uninstall()
if ($appuninstall.returnvalue -eq 0)
        {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Programm Successfully Removed"
        }    
    else
        {
        write-host -ForegroundColor red "There was a problem uninstalling the program"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$LastExitCode` is only set when running native commands (external .exes). In your code, you want to capture the result of the call to `Uninstall()` in a variable then use the return code property from that object in your `if` statement.